# Private Deployment of SQL Server CE 3.5 causes error using SqlCeConnection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, sql-server-ce

Greeting,

I'm trying to do private deployment for the SQL Server Compact. I followed everything correctly in : http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html but still no luck :(

It give me an error saying that

> Reference required to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the base class 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'. Add one to your project.

I had confirmed that I have System.Data added in my Reference, actually the problem MIGHT be due to incorrect version of the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` in the PRIVATE folder. It's 3.5.1.0 (If I use the one available in the Reference window), and 3.5.1.50 (If I use the PRIVATE dll).

Below is one of my code that give error. The error appear in `SqlCeConnection`.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO

Module dbConnection

    Public databaseConn As SqlCeConnection

    Public Function openConn() As SqlCeConnection
        If IsNothing(databaseConn) Then
        ElseIf databaseConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            databaseConn.Close()
        End If

        databaseConn = New SqlCeConnection("Persist Security Info = False; Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)) + "\sanyodb.sdf")

        Try
            databaseConn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Cannot open database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        End Try

        Return databaseConn
    End Function

    Public conn As New SqlCeConnection("Persist Security Info = False; Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)) + "\sanyodb.sdf")
End Module
```

This is a Smart Device Project, I'm using VS 2008, Compact Framework v3.5 to do the development. My coding language used is VB.NET.

Please advice what can I do? Actually what I want to approach is to deploy my application on the device SD card and make sure it still work even if the device got a hard reset.

Thanks!

Regards,
Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post does not apply to Windows Mobile Projects, as stated in the beginning of the post "the OS must be XP SP3 or higher". To do private deployment with Windows Mobile, extract all required files from the correct cab files, and simply include them with your project as content

Comment: Hallow, sorry it's my mistake not looking properly throughout the thing~ Is there a proper guide for private deployment with Window Mobile? I'm afraid I got the wrong files or something else is missing. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry because I'm a little bit confused. If I include them with my project as content, does that mean all the required files inside the cab will be together with the Application Folder? How do I know which cab is required actually?